# Who first considered the $f$ in $f(x)$ as an object in itself, and who decided to call it a function?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, terminology, calculus

The question is in the title, but allow me to provide some background.

I’m aware that Leibniz introduced the word “function” into mathematics (around 1673) and that [Johann Bernoulli or Euler](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/5204/3462) introduced the notation $f(x)$ (sometimes between 1706-1740). I've also read the Wikipedia article on the [History of the function concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_function_concept) and the book [Die Analysis im Wandel und im Widerstreit](https://books.google.ch/books/about/Die_Analysis_im_Wandel_und_im_Widerstrei.html?id=0fzWrQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) by Spalt, plus a few other sources on the history of functions. But I haven't found the following addressed:

Looking at definitions* and uses of the word *function* among mathematicians up until the beginning of the 20th century, I see that they consistently call $y$ the function. By $y$ I mean the one in $y=f(x)$. Equivalently they call $f(x)$ the function. Actually they call $y$ a function *of $x$*, but they eventually drop the “of $x$” when it is clear from the context or irrelevant for the discussion. None of them ever consider $f$ as a mathematical object in itself.

This is in stark contrast to the modern definition, which calls $f$ the function, describes it as a rule or the like, and officially calls $f(x)$ something else (like the output of the function at input $x$ etc.).

The first mathematician I could find to distinguish clearly between $f$ and $f(x)$, with a definition similar to modern ones, was Cantor in 1895. But to my surprise he did not call $f$ a function but a “Belegung” (allocation). Here's my translation of what he wrote in [Beiträge zur Begründung der transfiniten Mengenlehre, I](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02124929), 1895, p.486:

> By an *,allocation of the set $N$ with elements of the set $M$'*  or
>   simply put, by an *,allocation of $N$ with $M$'* we understand a law,
>   through which with every element $n$ of $N$ is connected a certain
>   element of $M$, where one and the same element of $M$ may be used
>   repeatedly.
>
> The with $n$ connected element of $M$ is to a certain extent a unique
>   function of $n$ and may be denoted with $f(n)$; it shall be called the
>   *,allocation function of $n$'*; the corresponding allocation of $N$ shall be called $f(N)$.
>
> Two allocations $f_{1}(N)$ und $f_{2}(N)$ are called equal if and only
>   if, for all elements $n$ of $N$ the equation 
>   $$  f_{1}(n) = f_{2}(n),$$ holds, so that if for a single fixed element $n=n_{0}$ the
>   equation does not hold, $f_{1}(N)$ and $f_{2}(N)$ are characterised as
>   different allocations of $N$.
>
> [$\ldots$]
>
> The totality of all different allocations of $N$ with $M$ determines a
>   set with the elements $f(N)$; we call it the *,set of allocations of
>   $N$ with $M$'* and denote it with $(N\mid M)$. Hence: 
>   $$ (N\mid M)=\{ f(N) \}. $$

Notice that he keeps the traditional meaning of the word function, so it makes perfect sense to give $f$ (or as he writes $f(N)$) a new name.

**Two questions:**

1. Was Cantor the first person to treat $f$ as an object on its own and
   distinguish it from $f(x)$? In other words, was Cantor the
   first one to give the modern definition of a function?
2. When and why did it become standard to call $f$ a function, despite the
   established use of the word for $f(x)$ (and despite Cantor calling
   $f$ something else)?

<sub>* Several such historical definitions can be found at the end of the following MO question: [Formalizations of the idea that something is a function of something else?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307947/formalizations-of-the-idea-that-something-is-a-function-of-something-else).</sub>

Comment: Are you sure that 1895 is the first occurrence in Cantor?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. I found that quote of Cantor in Spalts book, but I haven't systematically searched Cantors works.

Comment: Cantor created the terminus "Belegungsmenge" in 1895. Besides its appearance in his paper of 1895 Cantor explains the terminus to Klein in a letter of July 17, 1895.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler: I did a PDF search of Cantors Gesammelte Abhandlungen, and apparently the words Belegung and Abbildung both appear for the first time in the 1895 article.

Comment: Not an answer, but in case you're interested in some references to historical papers on the development of the idea of a function, see the list I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79613/what-was-the-notation-for-functions-before-euler/80546#80546).

Comment: "None of them ever consider f as a mathematical object in itself." because nothing about this 'object' is known or relevant, except the propery of having such values. Most often f(x) is "for any x", while  the 'output' would be specifically f(x_0).

Comment: @sand1 based on your assumption, could you explain what became know or relevant about $f$ around 1900, that wasn't known before, and which cause $f$ to be suddenly considered one of the most central objects of mathematics?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cantor 1895 is predated at least by Dedekind in [§2](https://archive.org/stream/wassindundwasso00dedegoog#page/n28) of [*Was sind und was sollen die Zahlen?* (1888)](https://books.google.com/books?id=zoxKAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA6) ([translation](https://archive.org/stream/cu31924001586282#page/n63)):

> 21. Erklärung *). Unter einer **Abbildung** $\varphi$ eines Systems $S$ wird ein Gesetz verstanden, nach welchem zu jedem bestimmten Element $s$ von $S$ ein bestimmtes Ding **gehört**, welches das **Bild** von $s$ heißt und mit $\varphi(s)$ bezeichnet wird; wir sagen auch, daß $\varphi(s)$ dem Element $s$ **entspricht**, daß $\varphi(s)$ durch die Abbildung $\varphi$ aus $s$ **entsteht** oder **erzeugt** wird.
>
> ---
>
> *) Vergl. Dirichlet's [Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie, dritte Auflage, 1879, §. 163](https://archive.org/stream/vorlesungenberz00dirigoog#page/n490).

(The footnote refers to a supplement in *Dedekind's* edition of Dirichlet.) 
Also, Dedekind in [§11](https://archive.org/stream/wassindundwasso00dedegoog#page/n65) clearly distinguishes between a *map* $\psi$ and what he still calls the *function $\psi(n)$ it determines*:

> 135. Erklärung. Es liegt nahe, die im Satze 126 dargestellte Definition einer
>   Abbildung $\psi$ der Zahlenreihe $N$ oder der durch dieselbe
>   bestimmten **Funktion** $\psi(n)$ auf den Fall anzuwenden, wo ($\ldots$)

**Edit:** To your two questions,

1. Attribution to Dedekind 1888 seems confirmed by W. Sieg and D. Schlimm,  [*Dedekind's Abstract Concepts: Models and Mappings*, Philosophia Mathematica nku021 (2014) 1-26](https://dx.doi.org/10.1093/philmat/nku021). They also quote from an earlier draft of 1872-78, where Dedekind wrote $x\,|\,f$ instead of $f(x)$.
2. I don't know who (rather unfortunately, I'd say) suppressed his careful distinction between **Abbildung** (mapping, application, "Maler", $f$) and **Funktion** (function, fonction, "Bild", $f(x)$). Perhaps von Neumann ([1925](http://emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?51.0163.04), [pp. 222, 223](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002169606&physid=phys227)):

   > ($\ldots$) aus einer Funktion $f$ (die von ihren Werten $f(x)$ wohl zu unterscheiden ist!) und einem Argumente $x$ den Wert $f(x)$ der Funktion $f$ für das Argument $x$ zu bilden. ($\ldots$) $\mathfrak M$ sei eine Menge, $f(x)$ eine (in $\mathfrak M$ definierte) Funktion.

   or more influentially van der Waerden in *Moderne Algebra* ([1930, §2, §6, §9](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-41906-9)):

   > Wenn durch irgend eine Vorschrift jedem Element $a$ einer Menge $\mathfrak M$ ein einziges neues Objekt $\varphi(a)$ zugeordnet wird, so nennen wir diese Zuordnung eine *Funktion* ($\ldots$) Man nennt eine solche Zuordnung ($\ldots$) auch eine (eindeutige) *Abbildung* der Menge $\mathfrak M$ auf die Menge ($\ldots$) Ist $\varphi$ eine eineindeutige Abbildung ($\ldots$) Eine solche Funktion $\varphi$ gibt es ($\ldots$)

Comment: Is my understanding correct, that the supplement of 1879 was written by Dedekind, that he defines Abbildungen already there, although he does not write $\phi(\omega)$ but only $\omega'$? Moreover in the supplement, he did not make explicit the relation between Abbildungen and Funktionen? So he does not call $n'$ a function of $n$, nor does he say that the $f$ from a function $f(x)$ is a map?

Comment: Yes, I think that's it exactly. After 1888 Dedekind names many maps ($f$) and many functions ($y=f(x)$), but the $\psi(n)$ quote above is the only place I've seen him relate both in the same breath. Such quotes by anyone seem hard to come by – one would be by C. S. Peirce, is a [1911 dictionary article](https://books.google.com/books?id=8jpAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA518&dq=function) where he proposes to translate *Abbildung* by *imaging*: "Any mathematical function of one variable may be regarded as an image of its variable according to some mode of imaging."

Comment: I was wondering if the terminology "Maler" for map is something you have seen in the literature of that time.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold Not seen by me in anything published at the time. Sieg-Schlimm quote *abbildende Maler* vs. *Bild* from a letter of Dedekind (1890) printed in Sinaceur ([1974](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=504946), p. 276).

Comment: But what about Dirichlet?  Didn't he use a symbol to denote a function when he defined a function as a rule that associates, etc.?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Per wiki quote linked in the question, [Dirichlet](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044089599187;view=1up;seq=168) called $y$, not $f$, the function.

Comment: @MikhailKatz adding to Francois comment: Dirichlet does talk about rules (Gesetze) which describe the dependence of $y$ from $x$, and he also uses the symbol $f$ (but only in the combination $f(x)$). But he never seems to explicitly identify $f$ with these "rules", nor does he give $f$ a name.

Answer (score 6):

**Answering 2:** Maybe the idea of calling $f$ the function goes back to Frege? In [Was ist eine Funktion?](https://archive.org/details/festschriftludw00meyegoog) Festschrift Ludwig Boltzmann (1904, pp. 656-666) we find on p. 663:

> Und haben wir hier nicht das, was wir suchen, die Funktion? Also wird
>   auch »$f$« genaugenommen eine Funktion andeuten.

My translation: "And don't we have here what we are looking for, the function? Hence also »$f$« will strictly speaking signify a function."

The whole article is a very interesting read, since Frege also tries to answer the questions "What is a variable quantity?" (he concludes they don't belong in mathematics), "What is an indeterminate number?" (he concludes there are none) and addresses the distinction between $f(x)$ as a syntactic expression (a term), versus $f(x)$ as a semantic entity (the variable quantity). I don't agree with all of his arguments, but it's fascinating to see how he single-handedly demolishes concepts that had been an integral part of mathematics for 200 years.

**Added later:** In the comments Francois makes the relevant observation, that Lagrange called $f$ the *caractéristique* of the function $f(x)$. One also finds this in Johann Bernoulli (in [*Remarques sur ce qu'on a donné jusqu'ici de solutions des Problemes sur les isoperimetres*](http://www.e-rara.ch/doi/10.3931/e-rara-3595), 1718, p. 243) and Euler (in [*Sur la vibration des cordes*](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E140.html), 1748, p. 78).

I interpret this similarly to Francois: $f$ is being treated merely a sign, that might helps us distinguish two functions, say $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. But $f$ was not yet considered as a mathematical object on its own. *On the other hand* in Peano's [*Arithmetices Principia*](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog) (1889, p. XIII) we find:

> Let $\phi$ be a sign, or aggregate of signs, such that if $x$ is an
>   entity of class $s$, the sign combination $\phi x$ determines a new
>   entity; we also suppose that equality is defined between the entities
>   $\phi x$; and if $x$ and $y$ are entities of the class $s$, and $x=y$,
>   we suppose that it can be deduced that $\phi x = \phi y$. Then the
>   sign $\phi$ is said to be a *prefix sign for a function in the
>   class $s$*, and we write $\phi \, \backepsilon \, F`s$.

(Translation adapted from Johan Granström's [PhD thesis](https://intuitionistic.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/theses_published_uppsala.pdf).)

My interpretation here is that Peano *does* treat $f$ as a mathematical object on its own, distinct from $f(x)$, just like his contemporaries, Frege, Dedekind and Cantor, *yet* he calls $f$ a *sign for a function*, just like Bernoulli, Euler and Lagrange.

(So I'm left with the feeling, that I first need to define more precisely what it means to *treat something as a mathematical object*, in order for my interpretations or even my question to make sense. But currently I'm not able to provide such a definition.)

Comment: ...so Frege tries to argue that it's wrong to talk of variable quantities in mathematics and that $y$ should not be called a function, as it had been done for 200 years.

Comment: Interesting! However, I feel that whatever he’s calling function does *not* fit our “modern definition” as in Q1 (e.g. as graph). In fact, contrast even the title question with what he literally writes in *Function und Begriff* ([1891, p. 19](https://archive.org/stream/functionundbegr00freggoog#page/n27/mode/1up/search/Gegenstande)): [***“Graphs of functions are objects, whereas functions themselves are not.”***](https://books.google.com/books?id=YIxYAAAAYAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22Graphs+of+functions+are+objects%2C+whereas+functions+themselves+are+not%22)

Comment: He details that even more forcefully in *Grundgesetze der Arithmetik II* ([1903, §147, footnote 2](https://archive.org/stream/bub_gb_LZ5tAAAAMAAJ#page/n465)): for him, $f(\xi)=g(\xi)$ for all $\xi$ does *not* imply $f=g$.

Comment: I agree and feel similarly that I haven't understood fully what he's calling a function. I suspect that a modern computer scientist/type theorist might be better able to interpret him. For example, the property in your preceding comment is nowadays called function extensionality, and there are type theories where it doesn't hold. Or Freges distinction between "Funktion" and "Werteverlauf einer Funktion" (see Funktion und Begriff) might be interpreted as the distinction between $f$ and $\lambda x. f(x)$, which can be identified _if_ we assume Churchs Eta-conversion. But (cont.)

Comment: ...as a traditionally trained mathematician I feel out of my depth in these matters.

Comment: At any rate, what you say is precisely confirmed by Bernays’ *Axiomatic set theory* ([1958, p. 61](https://books.google.com/books?id=pDh9fioSraIC&pg=PA61)): What we call function is the extensional thing  Frege called *Wertverlauf* (= graph, in the above-quoted translation) — hence is *not* what Frege himself called function.

Comment: A somewhat relevant discussion on intensional/extensional functions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156238

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler But I believe we agree, that he clearly distinguishes between f(x) and f and in 1904 calls f the function. Whatever it is that he understood by f.

Comment: Yes, he calls f (and not f(x)) the function. Have you found anyone else doing this before van der Waerden 1930? Side remark: Lagrange in *Mécanique analytique* and *Théorie des fonctions analytiques* also routinely called f (and not f(x)) a name: *la caractéristique*. But I doubt he meant much more by this than just the letter (Buchstabe).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler I haven't yet looked into what happened between Frege and van der Waerden. If I had time I would try Russell, Peano and the people who influenced van der Waerden. Concerning _caractéristique_ see my edits to this answer.

Comment: Good catch of *caractéristique* in Bernoulli — likely a first, coming right after his famous definition of “function”. @MauroALLEGRANZA also noted this in the [answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/5204) you linked.

Comment: I should add that before he started using *caractéristique* (apparently in [1773](http://bibliothek.bbaw.de/bbaw/bibliothek-digital/digitalequellen/schriften/anzeige/index_html?band=03-nouv/1771&seite:int=194), p. 191), Lagrange was much looser: e.g. in [1761](http://www.archive.org/stream/mlangesdephilo02soci#page/n246) one finds both ***la fonction φ(x)*** or similar (pp. 13, 70, 91, 99, 116, 119,...), and ***la fonction φ*** (pp. 44, 49, 63, 69-73, 86, 91-92, 95-96, 119, 154, 160,...). So that's a possible answer to your Question 2.